# How can I check if a subroutine has been run before?

Tags: memory-leaks, fortran

I've currently got a Fortran program using the 2008 standard that has a subroutine that loads data from a file if it's the first run of the subroutine. On all runs, the subroutine interpolates over the data and returns two values, but the goal is to avoid reloading the same data from the file.

Initially, I had something like this:

```
module myModel_mod
    use myModelLoader_mod
    use linear_interpolation_module
    implicit none
    contains
    subroutine myModel(A, B, C, modelFile, D, E)
        real :: A, B, C, D, E
        character(len=*) :: modelFile
        type(linear_interp_3d), save :: F, G
        real, dimension(:), allocatable, save :: As, Bs, Cs
        if (.not. allocated(As)) then
            call loadModel(modelFile, As, Bs, Cs)
            .
            .  (processing of loaded data and creation of F and G occurs here)
            .
        end if
        call F%evaluate(A, B, C, D)
        call G%evaluate(A, B, C, E)
    end subroutine
end module
```

My module makes use of the [finterp](https://github.com/jacobwilliams/finterp) library. It interpolates a 3D gridded data set for two values, D and E. I'm having to rewrite this part of the code to fix a memory leak, and I'd like to fix where `As`, `Bs`, and `Cs` are left allocated. They don't need the SAVE attribute; it's left over from an older implementation of gridded interpolation I was using. However, if I remove it, then by my understanding, I can't check if `As` is allocated to see if the subroutine has been run before.

I've considered creating a logical flag variable with the SAVE attribute that gets set when the subroutine runs for the first time, but I believe that would still result in a small memory leak, albeit much smaller than what I currently have.

Is there a way to check for the "first run" condition in a way that doesn't result in a memory leak?

Comment: What do you call a "memeory leak"? I do not see any potential for anything that is typically called "memory leak".

Comment: In a lot of the code, variables are allocated and haven't been deallocated. As a result, running the main function (which calls this subroutine) multiple times in one program execution continuously allocates more memory without freeing it. The allocation here is done in the omitted part of the `if` statement, which is a set of `if` statements that remove redundant entries from the loaded data.

Comment: I  recommend to make the arrays module variables and create a clean-up subroutine. Bur with allocatable arrays there can't be true memory leaks. The memory is always accessible and youbcannot allocate ad infinitum.

Comment: @VladimirF Alright, I see how this could be done with module variables, but how is the memory always accessible? Aren't the variables defined within the subroutine accessible only from within the subroutine? And if they don't have the save attribute, aren't they inaccessible even from within the subroutine on its next call?

Comment: Local allocatable arrays that are not saved are automatically deallocated per the rules of Fortran 95.

Comment: Vladimir is quite right, your  worries about the memory growing are not correct for allocatable arrays. But to add another way, because I try to avoid saved variables and keep my subroutines as pure as possible, in my view this routine is doing multiple different things. I would therefore split it into at least 3 parts and call whichever is required by the programme logic as required, and so hopefully avoid the requirement for internal state information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory leaks are impossible with allocatable arrays in Fortran. Unsaved allocatable local variables are deallocated on exit from the procedure. The saved ones are retained but cannot grow without limits.  You have only a limited number of local allocatable variables that you can allocate and that then take some memory, but they will not grow without control.

To answer your title question, I use the approach with a saved logical variable and if it is about allocating local or module arrays I just use `if (allocated())`.